# React and Typescript dynamic component from config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a dynamic menu system with reactjs and typescript.

My config looks like this:

```
import {TableIcon} from "@heroicons/react/solid";

type route = {
    icon: React.ReactNode,
    path: string,
    title: string,
}

export const navRoutes = () : route[] => {
    return [
        {
            icon: TableIcon,
            path: '/',
            title: 'Home'
        },
    ]
}
```

in my nav component, I'm doing

```
{navRoutes().map((item) => (
    <a key={item.title} href={item.path}>
        <item.icon /> // also tried {item.icon}
        {item.title}
    </a>
))}
```

I'm getting an error that `TS2604: JSX element type 'item.icon' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

I've done similar things without typescript that worked as expected-- can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React.ReactNode` is the type of a rendered component. For example:

```
const a: React.ReactNode = <TableIcon />
```

If you want to pass in some *rendered* JSX, that's what you would use. But it sounds like you want to pass in a a functional component with no props, which will *then* be rendered.

`React.FC` is the generic type of a react functional component with no props. That's probably the type you want.

```
type route = {
    icon: React.FC,
    path: string,
    title: string,
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=4&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BvOAFRQCMAbJASTQgDs4BfObLjgAiAAIALJDmCcuAZwD0RdDAVyIzYABNhAblKkYATzBI4OAK4wzAXhqk4juDO4AuRMRgA6AGIBhABoHJzAUGHF3ORgoYC4AcyCnOBhgGFZI6NiE0l4DJAAPSnhZKLguFAA3BAgrJDk4OwAKAEo4d0trAG0AXQaAPnskohgLKB5O4KTHakmppJcudwYWdllEuanQ8Pd8BXx1jacUtKQdgAlcJDJD3gO4bpyDTAsuDGBuOB8ICBbB8yQRmMypVqrU5C0vCAUGBGo1UkgQK0bANGrMADwoOAAayQRhs1HhIC8x1Y-HEREw+MJXi24l4fVmSTR1IWcAUAwUCjgKGY6mSMSQWhoLNkuUOBOsRJJSDFTjRChQDOazRyQA)

Answer (score 2):

The type `React.ReactNode` describes the returned value from calling a JSX component rather than the component itself. You can either:

1 ) Pass a `React.ReactNode`:

```
type route = {
  icon: React.ReactNode;
  path: string;
  title: string;
};

export const navRoutes = (): route[] => {
  return [
    {
      icon: <TableIcon />,
      path: "/",
      title: "Home"
    }
  ];
};

{navRoutes().map((item) => (
  <a key={item.title} href={item.path}>
    {item.icon}
    {item.title}
  </a>
))}
```

2. Pass a callable component.  Usually you need to give it an uppercase name in order to call it through JSX.  Somehow `<item.icon/>` seems like it works? But to be safe I would capitalize it.

```
type route = {
  icon: React.ComponentType;
  path: string;
  title: string;
};

export const navRoutes = (): route[] => {
  return [
    {
      icon: TableIcon,
      path: "/",
      title: "Home"
    }
  ];
};

{navRoutes().map(({title, path, icon: Icon}) => (
  <a key={title} href={path}>
    <Icon/>
    {title}
  </a>
))}
```

By default `React.ComponentType` doesn't take any props (other than children).  If you want to pass props when you call your `<Icon/>` you can use `React.ComponentType<SomePropsType>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSX.Element instead of React.ReactNode, that's what `@heroicons/react` returns as a type

Footer Social Icons (added the TableIcon for this example)

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import cn from 'classnames';
import {
    Facebook,
    Instagram,
    SquareLogo
} from '@/components/UI/Icons';
import { TableIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid';
import css from './footer.module.css';

export interface FooterSocialProps {
    href: string;
    label: string;
    id: number;
    icon: JSX.Element;
}

export const footerSocial: FooterSocialProps[] = [
    {
        href: 'https://www.facebook.com/thefaderoominc/?ref=py_c',
        label: 'Facebook',
        id: 0,
        icon: <Facebook />
    },
    {
        href: 'https://www.instagram.com/thefaderoomhighlandpark/',
        label: 'Instagram',
        id: 1,
        icon: <Instagram />
    },
    {
        href: 'https://squareup.com/gift/MLHZCDVC0MKB1/order',
        label: 'Square Giftcards',
        id: 2,
        icon: <SquareLogo />
    },
    {
        href: 'https://stackoverflow.com/example',
        label: 'Table Icon',
        id: 3,
        icon: <TableIcon />
    }
];

export interface FooterSocialPropsFC {
    className?: string;
}

const FooterSocial: FC<FooterSocialPropsFC> = ({
    className
}) => {
    return (
        <div className={cn(css.socialRoot, className)}>
            {footerSocial.map((social, i) => (
                <div key={++i}>
                    <a
                        title={social.label}
                        target='__blank'
                        href={social.href}
                        className={cn(
                            css.socialLink,
                            'text-olive-300 hover:text-olive-400  text-opacity-80'
                        )}
                    >
                        <span className='sr-only'>
                            {`External Link to The Fade Room's ${social.label} page`}
                        </span>
                        {social.icon}
                    </a>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default FooterSocial;
```